# How to create a Microsoft Teams invitation in a vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-teams

I have an application that schedules meetings, but i need that when the user presses the  "Finish" button a Microsoft Teams invitation will be sent to an e-mail list.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/

Comment: @Gabriel - Are you using Graph API to schedule the meetings in teams from your current application?

Comment: Please have a look at this doc- :-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved or still looking for any help?